# Converse of the first fundamental homomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have a question arising from the "Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem" as applied to groups (i.e. that the existence of a homomorphism $h: G\to H$ with kernel $J$ implies $H$ is isomorphic to the quotient group $G/J$).

As I understand it, Category Theory can be used to show that the rough converse is also true - i.e., that if a quotient group $G/J$ (where $J$ is a normal subgroup of $G$) is isomorphic to some group $H$, then there is a homomorphism $h: G\to H$ with kernel $J$.

Is this correct?

If so, is there a proof of the latter using only ideas from "standard" undergrad algebra?

Comment: FHT? Is that a standard acronym?

Comment: Do you mean Freed-Hopkins-Teleman?

Comment: @Joe: almost certainly not (look at the phrase "assuming the relevant quotient group consists cosets of a normal subgroup"). It sounds like the OP is talking about one of the isomorphism theorems, but if so, I'm not sure which one and what the OP means by its converse.

Comment: @iser54301: yes, this is the easy direction. More or less by definition, there's a natural map $G \to G/J$ where $g$ is sent to the coset $g + J$, and more or less by definition, this is a homomorphism.

Comment: There is a canonical surjective homomorphism $q: G\rightarrow G/J$ with kernel $J$. If $G/J$ is isomorphic to $H$ via $i$, then $i\circ q$ is the desired surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy direction: there is a natural map $q: G\rightarrow G/N$, given by $g\mapsto gN$. If $i: G/N\cong H$, then $q\circ i$ is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ onto $H$ with kernel $N$.

Comment: I understand the logic of what will map into what to create the homomorphism, but the part I am having trouble with is the kernel.  Also, I am not familiar with your notation in the definition of i .  Does your notation mean there is some function i that maps G/N onto some set that is isomorphic to H?

Comment: So, you're asking how we know the kernel of $q$ is exactly $N$? Well, this amounts to showing that $gN=N$ iff $g\in N$. Well, clearly $g\in gN$, so $gN=N$ implies $g\in N$. In the other direction, if $g\in N$, then for $a\in N$ we have $a=gg^{-1}a$; since $N$ is a subgroup, $g^{-1}\in N$, so $gg^{-1}a\in gN$. But this means that $N\subseteq gN$. Meanwhile, certainly $gN\subseteq N$ if $g\in N$, since $N$ is closed under the group operation. So we're done.

Comment: Note that we're not using normality here at all - we have a map *of sets* from the set $G$ to the set of cosets of $N$, given by $g\mapsto gN$, and  the preimage of the coset $eN=N$ is precisely $N$. Normality comes into play when we try to turn the set of cosets of $N$ into a group.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.